# How to install the latest version of OpenSSL on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, openssl

I see that the latest security patches are not yet available from `apt-get install openssl` on Ubuntu 14.04. What steps do I need to take in order to install the latest OpenSSL without conflicting with my previous installation through `apt-get`?

Comment: What security patches do you mean? Are you aware that Ubuntu backports patches into older version? http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.11/changelog

Comment: I'm referring to [this article](http://www.zdnet.com/article/high-severity-flaw-in-openssl-to-be-patched/) and this recommendation: "Upgrade your OpenSSL package to one of the following versions: 1.0.2a, 1.0.1m, 1.0.0r and 0.9.8zf"

Comment: When I run `openssl version -a` I see `OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014` which makes me think I don't have the latest version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check this page
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/openssl
It will show you the exact security updates that have been backported, even though the overall version date appears old.  If you have installed the latest openssl via apt-get upgrade, you are current (on security updates) as of 2015-03-19, which happens to be 2 days after the security flaw was posted on your link above.  You can drill down into the openssl page on ubuntu to see if this fix was included.

Comment: where at that link can you see which security updates have been backported?